# Como passar uma função personizada dentro de um evento Change do Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Bom dia gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso dentro do Jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(teste());
  
  function teste() {
    alert($("select").val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">valor 3</option>
</select>
```

aparentemente ele consegue chamar o evento no momento da execução, porém ao alterar o valor do select não.

Comment: Qual resultado pretendes obter? Explique melhor.

Comment: use `$("select").change(teste);` ao invés de `$("select").change(teste());`.

Comment: Deu certo Benilson, mas e se caso eu quiser enviar um parâmentro para minha função, como eu faria? por exemplo: `$("select").change(teste('par1'));`

Comment: Usa uma função anônima recebendo o parâmetro e executando internamente `teste(parametro)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problema

Quando você faz isso:

```
$("select").change(teste());
```

Você executa o "teste()" e passa para a função "change" o retorno de teste, assim o evento "change" não faz nada.

## Solução

Passando somente "teste" você passa de fato a função para "change".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(teste);
  
  function teste() {
    alert($("select").val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">valor 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: e como faria para passar um parâmetro para a função teste?

Comment: Não da para personalizar o parâmetro, você pode ver na [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/change/) que o único parâmetro é "Event", ou seja, você tem que trabalhar com isso, e la dentro você pode chamar outra função ou fazer como você fez selecionando o próprio elemento.

Comment: @WictorChaves é possível sim. A própria documentação diz como. Elaborei uma resposta pra complementar. Tmj

Comment: @LipESprY Massa! Vivendo e aprendendo +1

Answer (score 2):

É possível sim. Veja o que diz a [documentação do método change do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/change/).

**Exemplo #1 - passando o nome da função:**

```js
function teste(ev){
    alert($("select").val());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(teste); // aqui passo o nome da função a ser executada
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">valor 1</option>
    <option value="2">valor 2</option>
    <option value="3">valor 3</option>
</select>
```

**Exemplo #2 - função anônima:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function(ev){ // pode ser arrow function também: (ev) => alert($("select").val());
        alert($("select").val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">valor 1</option>
    <option value="2">valor 2</option>
    <option value="3">valor 3</option>
</select>
```

**Exemplo #3 - passando dados específicos para a função:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(
        'Você selecionou o valor: ', // aqui eu defino o que quero passar pra função
        (ev) => alert(ev.data+$("select").val())  // com ev.data eu recupero o que passei por argumento
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">valor 1</option>
    <option value="2">valor 2</option>
    <option value="3">valor 3</option>
</select>
```

Observe que passe a `string` `'Você selecionou o valor: '` que poderia ser qualquer outro tipo, como um objeto, por exemplo...

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer desta forma, passando o evento para uma função não-anônima junto com parâmetros:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change("param", teste);
  
  function teste(event) {
    console.log("Valor selecionado:", $("select").val());
    console.log("Parâmetro:", event.data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">valor 3</option>
</select>
```

O parâmetro é passado na propriedade `.data` do evento, que poderia ser também um array ou um objeto:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(['a','b'], teste);
  
  function teste(event) {
    console.log("Valor selecionado:", $("select").val());
    console.log("Parâmetro em forma de array:", event.data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">valor 3</option>
</select>
```